# Unicode in data-content for pseudo element content

Tags: jquery, css, unicode, pseudo-element

I would like to put unicode in the data-content attribute using JQuery so as to use it for pseudo element content, but I can't find the right format. How do you display unicode? The fallowing just displays `&#x25BC;`.

```css
a::after
{
    content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<a href="...">...</a>
```

```javascript
$("a").attr ("data-content", "&#x25BC;");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert in this format, using the `\u` that, in Javascript, denotes an Unicode number inside a string literal

```
$("a").attr ("data-content", "\u25BC");
```

From [**MDN Unicode escape docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode_escape_sequences):

> You can use the Unicode escape sequence in string literals, regular expressions, and identifiers. The escape sequence consists of six ASCII characters: \u and a four-digit hexadecimal number. For example, \u00A9 represents the copyright symbol. Every Unicode escape sequence in JavaScript is interpreted as one character.

```js
$("a").attr ("data-content",  "\u25BC");
```

```css
a::after
{
    content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="...">...</a>
```

Comment: Or just paste the Unicode character itself: `$("a").attr ("data-content",  "▼");`