# Changing CSS Unicode Content Property Dynamically

Tags: css, css-content

I am setting up a background in a div tag that is a font awesome icon in each row of a table. This icon depends on the object that is being displayed. I tried setting up the code similar to [Changing CSS content property dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258880/changing-css-content-property-dynamically). However, my data-content would be a unicode. I am assigning the values in an angular controller as follows:

```
if (type) {
    if (type.image.includes('fa-hand-o-up')) {
        type.background = '\f0a6';
    } else if (type.image.includes('fa-wrench')) {
        type.background = '\f0ad';
    } else if (type.image.includes('fa-star')) {
        type.background = '\f005';
    }            
    return type;
}
```

and then including them in the table as follows:

```
<td>
    <div class="text-center type-wrapper" 
         data-content="{{::dataItem.type.background}}">
        <span class="bold">{{::dataItem.type.name}}</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

However, this just puts 0a6, 0ad, and 005 as the background 'image'. Is there a way to add unicode content dynamically or is the attr(data-xxx) just for plain text?

Also, I tried adding a attr(data-color) for color, but that doesn't seem to work either.  Is that also because I am using hex code instead of plain text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197443/use-fontawesome-icon-inside-a-before-pseudo-element-with-attr

Comment: The methods described do work, but not for AngularJS. The problem with them is that you need to hard-code the values into the data-content attribute in the HTML. I need something dynamic using Angular. After some investigation, I would need some kind of ng-xxx attribute to add to the page. There is a ng-attr-xxx that you can supposedly use, but I could not get that to work. There is also an ng-style, but you would need to build the style somewhere, which would then be mixing styles in the controller more than I would like.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>If I got your question correctly...</sup>  
try prefixing with `&#x` reference

```css
span:before{
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<span data-content="&#x00ff;"></span>
```

references start with `&#` and end with `;` and the `x` means that what's used is a **hexadecimal** value.

Comment: That works if I am able to hard-code the HTML. However, I am running this in an ng-repeat with the content depending on the dataItem.type for that record. For Angular, it appears that you can only use ng-xxx to get dynamic attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26025865/2077405

> Insert in this format, using the \u that, in Javascript, denotes an
>   Unicode number inside a string literal
>
> ```
> $("a").attr ("data-content", "\u25BC");
> ```

Comment: Works for me in a project where I need to dynamically change a ::before content with the unicode of fontawesome